# Which universities/colleges teach Microsoft ASP.NET and other MS technologies?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saw "[Which universities teach Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543223/which-universities-teach-python)", so I thought I would ask one about Microsoft technologies. Do you know of any schools that teach beginning to advanced Microsoft programming languages?

Comment: I work almost exclusively in the MS stack, and trust me - you do *not* want to attend a school that 'specializes' in any particular technology, *especially* MS. You go to school to learn how to learn technologies.

Comment: Have you read Joel's articles about Java-only Schools? Well, .Net-only Schools are only slightly less evil. You should go to college to learn how to be a programmer, and thus learn how to learn to use all frameworks. And also algorithms! That's a core part of your education too!

Comment: Sadly, far too many universities have such an anti-microsoft bias that they teach nothing about the MS stack even if they do cover a variety of other platforms. Sad since the MS stack is quite good, and is popular in the real business world. It puts newer programmers at a disadvantage when they first enter the workforce even if it otherwise did give them a solid foundation in general concepts.

Comment: University of Hull, teaches C# programming in Computer Science, they also have a couple of MSc in .NET. http://www2.hull.ac.uk/ug/courses/computer-science.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neumont University has a Microsoft Software focus as an option.

http://www.neumont.edu/

Comment: Many commented that one shouldn't choose a college based on the technologies used. However, I simply asked if there is a college out there that teaches the MS stack from beginning to advanced stages. Neumont appears to do this. So I must mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Let me be the first to say that I recommend that you avoid choosing a college based on the the specific technologies it uses.  When I went to college, IBM and DEC (Digital Equipment Corporation) were the biggest technologies.  My college used DEC systems, and that helped me get my first couple programming jobs after college; however, I think that probably would have been true for whatever technology I used in school.  Now, IBM is not as big a force as they were - at least in the sense of dominating the hardware market - and DEC no longer exists as an independent entity (bought by Compaq which was bought by HP).  I've learned Unix and Windows to stay employable.

Comment: True, but it seems like many colleges simply avoid MS technologies. Perhaps I should have rephrased my question to ask which colleges teach a variety of technologies instead of just one platform.

Answer (score 11):

**Would Von Neumann or Turing approve?**

Use the [Microsoft Academy locator](http://www.microsoft.com/education/msitacademy/itaplocator.mspx) ... Think "Microsoft Youth" and you get the idea.

I think universities should teach C and Lisp and move upwards. As it is harder to move down. All this Java/C# shit should come later. Even Python is a better option than Java IMHO. I dislike the Microsoft strategy of giving schools free stuff to create armies of zombies, read "I can only use [Word|Excel|C#|Access|MS-SQL]"

If I could change things, they would learn:

1. **Theory first**
2. Get started with **C/Unix** with exercises that get results and smiles
3. **Lisp and SICP crash-course to open their minds** a bit
4. Move onto a SIMPLE OOP language like Python (minus decorators)
5. Then look at other languages and *examine* in an imperical way, *why* they exist, and where they differ ... then do a few projects in each.

But hey, it's your education. Don't listen to me, I'm not a computer science graduate.

Comment: Note that the Academy locator appears to be broken.  I gave it a couple cities and it referred me to places in states I had not selected.  Other than that +1.

Comment: @Chris, Yea it is a bit shit. Mind you, probably ASP.NET

Comment: Any competent university will realize that theory comes first, and teach accordingly. Whether theory is taught through C/C++/Java/MS is moot at that point.

Comment: @Jagd ... maybe so, but I have seen courses that mangle theory and Java. The science gets lost.

Comment: @Aiden.  I figured it's using LINQ. ;)

Comment: +1! Every programmer should be forced to use a unix on their personal computer for at least 1 semester. If they did that *everyone* would be ready for Flash to be replaced!

Answer (score 4):

Well I am a CS Grad and currently using Microsoft Technologies and I completely 
 agree with @GreenMatt, it is not good to go for a course centred around particular Platform / tools but not the core concepts

Any way if this is your choice have a look at Sheffield Hallam University, being parter organisation and training centre for Microsoft, it also offers some degree courses based arround Microsoft such as the following

- [Microsoft Dynamics
  Programmes(MBA)](http://www.shu.ac.uk/prospectus/computing/info_systems/)
- [Dynamics Programme as a whole](http://www.shu.ac.uk/computing/microsoft/)

One more thing, these tools and technologies are evolving so quickly and more and more are coming in every other day, Consider this..

1. 6 months ago I was using "Hard coded
   queries to get data from DB"
2. about 3 months ago I started using
   Designer generated Data Sets and
   Table Adapters
3. Now the new project has been
   approved with use of "LINQ to SQL" for Data Acess Layer.

All 3 are from Microsoft, along with 2 dozen other technologies

Honestly, by the time you will be out of schools, for professionals you will sound like talking about history of programming !!!!

You will learn twice as more tools each month than you will learn at school per semester, but won't be able to develop that very "skills set" and "art for programming", if you miss / avoid
"data structures", "Algorithms", "Discrete Mathematics" and "Object oriented Programming Concepts" or similar Subjects.

**So moral of the story**

Strong concepts and skills / approach towards problem solving will help you always, never the tools.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

[University of South Florida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_South_Florida) uses C# and VB.NET in some of its more advanced courses. Gateway courses are all Java and C, though.

Answer (score 0):

At my university (Polytechnique, Montreal), the language of predilection for teaching procedural + object oriented programming is C++. However, we use Visual Studio as an IDE (one could say we do learn some Microsoft technologies).